# Task.StartNew() vs Parallel.ForEach : Multiple Web Requests Scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have read through all the related questions in SO, but a little confused on the best approach for my scenario where multiple web service calls are fired.

I have an aggregator service that takes an input, parses and translates it into multiple web requests, makes the web request calls (unrelated, so could be fired in parallel) and consolidates the response which is sent back to the caller. The following code is used right now -

```
list.ForEach((object obj) =>
{
     tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((object state) => 
     {
           this.ProcessRequest(obj);
     }, obj, CancellationToken.None,
     TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default));
});
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

the `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` comes from Scott Hanselman's [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToParallelBasicsDontBlockYourThreadsMakeAsyncIOWorkForYou.aspx) where it is said that

> "A better solution from a scalability perspective, says Stephen, is to
> take advantage of asynchronous I/O.  When you're calling out across
> the network, there's no reason (other than convenience) to blocks
> threads while waiting for the response to come back"

The existing code appears to consume too many threads and the Processor Time shoots up to 100% on production load and that gets me thinking.

The other alternate is to use Parallel.ForEach which uses a partitioner but and also "blocks" the call, which is fine for my scenario.

Considering this is all "Async IO" work and not "CPU bound" work, and the web requests are not long running (return in max 3 seconds), I tend to believe the existing code is good enough. But would this provide better throughput than Parallel.ForEach? Parallel.ForEach probably uses "minimal" number of Tasks because of the partitioning and therefore optimal use of threads(?). I did test Parallel.ForEach with some local tests and it doesn't appear to be any better.

The goal is to reduce the CPU time and increase throughput and therefore better scalability. Is there a better approach for handling web requests in parallel?

Appreciate any inputs, thanks.

**EDIT:**
ProcessRequest method shown in the code sample indeed uses HttpClient and its async methods to fire requests (PostAsync, GetAsync, PutAsync).

Comment: If `ProcessRequest` uses asynchronous methods, why are you calling it inside `Task.Factory.StartNew`? You could simply add the Task it returns to your list. If you are actually blocking inside it, it doesn't matter that you use asynchronous methods in parts of it. The final blocking call negates any benefits

Comment: "other than convenience" well, that's a pretty good reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> makes the web request calls (unrelated, so could be fired in parallel)

What you actually want is to call them *concurrently*, not in *parallel*. That is, "at the same time", not "using multiple threads".

> The existing code appears to consume too many threads

Yeah, I think so too. :)

> Considering this is all "Async IO" work and not "CPU bound" work

Then it should all be done asynchronously, and *not* using task parallelism or other parallel code.

As Antii pointed out, you should make your asynchronous code asynchronous:

```
public async Task ProcessRequestAsync(...);
```

Then what you want to do is consume it using *asynchronous concurrency* (`Task.WhenAll`), not *parallel concurrency* (`StartNew`/`Run`/`Parallel`):

```
await Task.WhenAll(list.Select(x => ProcessRequestAsync(x)));
```

Comment: Parallel and concurrent are synonyms.  When using "parallel" in this answer it seems that you meant "multithreaded".  `Then it should all be done asynchronously, and not using TPL or parallel code.`  It shouldn't be using `StartNew` or `Run` of the TPL; using the TPL to manage tasks representing asynchronous work would be fine, as that's in fact what you've shown.  You're not "not using the TPL", you're just using it differently..

Comment: Disagree re "parallel" and "concurrent" terminology. But you are correct about TPL; I meant to say "task parallelism".

Comment: Doing things in parallel is doing multiple things at the same time.  You can do multiple things at the same time through the use of multiple threads, or through doing multiple inherently asynchronous operations at the same time.  Both operations result in parallelism.  The `Parallel` *class* in .NET has operations that all involve multithreading, and not any other means of accomplishing parallelism, but the general concept of "paralleism" or "doing this in parallel" is in no way specific to multiple threads.  What would make you think that it would be?

Comment: For common English, I agree they're synonyms. But it's beneficial as developers to distinguish between concurrency, parallelism, and asynchrony. I always use concurrency as the "parent" concept, with parallelism and asynchrony describing the specific approaches. Otherwise, the terminology gets confusing IMO.

Comment: But there's nothing about the term Parallelism, either in its broader English context, or even in a programming context, that makes it specific to the use of multiple threads.  Parallelism can be accomplished through the use of asynchrony or through the use of multithreading.  I agree that there are a lot of similar but subtly different terms here, and it is hard to keep them straight.  I'm just saying that the definitions are more that you have parallelism/concurrency as synonyms (even in a programming context) and that parallelism can be accomplished with either multithreading or asynchrony.

Comment: I'd say that trying to explain to people that "asynchrony cannot be used to accomplish parallelism" is going to cause quite a lot of confusion.  You can *absolutely* use asynchronous to do work in parallel; you do not require the use of multiple threads to do work in parallel.  If you use the term "multithreading" instead of "parallel" then you *do* have a term that specifically describes parallelism achieved through the use of multiple threads.

Comment: Funnily, I've been always using "parallelism" as a parent concept, with sub-concepts "concurrency" for concurrently racing multi-threaded actions, and "asynchrony" for paralleled pending operation blocking no threads :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are CPU bound (you are - "Processor Time shoots up to 100% ") you need to reduce CPU usage. Async IO does nothing to help with that. If anything it causes a little more CPU usage (unnoticeable here).

Profile the app to see what takes so much CPU time and optimize that code.

The way you initiate parallelism (Parallel, Task, async IO) does nothing to the efficiency of the parallel action itself. The network does not get faster if you call it in an async way. It's the same hardware still. Also no less CPU usage.

Determine the optimal degree of parallelism experimentally and choose a parallelism technique that is suitable for that degree. If it's a few dozen then threads are totally fine. If it's in the hundreds seriously consider async IO.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping synchronous calls inside Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't give you any benefits of async. You should use proper async functions for better scalability. Notice how Scott Hanselman makes async functions in post you are referring.

For example

```
public async Task<bool> ValidateUrlAsync(string url)
{
    using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)await WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync())
    return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok;
}
```

Checkout http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

So,
your ProcessRequest method should be implemented as async like

```
public async Task<bool> ProcessRequestAsync(...)
```

then you can just

```
tasks.Add(this.ProcessRequestAsync(obj))
```

If you start task with Task.Factory.StartNew it doesn't work as async even if your ProcessRequest method is internally making async calls. If you wanna use Task.Factory you should make your lambda also async like:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async (object state) => 
{
    await this.ProcessRequestAsync(obj);
}, obj, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,   TaskScheduler.Default));
```

Comment: Probably I missed to mention...actually, the ProcessRequest inturn makes calls to async versions of the HttpClient API - PostAsync, SendAsync and GetAsync based on the request (obj) passed in. Will update the question.

Comment: Add only async functions to your task list. Do not use Task.Factory.StartNew.

Comment: He is CPU bound. Async IO will not provide more throughput.

Comment: Well he said "Considering this is all "Async IO" work and not "CPU bound" work" and stated that he is using HttpClient for async web requests. How is this CPU bound?

Comment: It is CPU bound simply by the fact that he is driving the CPU to 100%. This is limiting the throughput he gets.

Comment: Well that is because he is blocking async from working by using Task.Factory.StartNew.

Comment: Blocking does not consume CPU (except a little constant amount). Blocking deschedules the thread from the CPU. Don't make the mistake of thinking that Thread.Sleep(100) burns 100ms of CPU time! It burns like .1ms of overhead for the kernel call and context switch.