# Web service call takes too long

Tags: c#, web-services

I created a client Webservice with C# to be able to retrieve informations about a book that i get from a server.

When i make the call to get books informations from bookIds that i pass in paremeters, sometimes the call is fast, sometimes it takes 1 min and sometimes it takes forever. I only store the bookIds in my dataBase, so when i need more informations about the books (title, dateOfPublication, etc) i contact the webService to get them. I'm using the chrome debugger and under the Network tab and i only have ***"CAUTION ; request is not finished yet"***...and no other informations that can help me to see what happens exactly! –

The function i call is `getBooksByAuthor(authorId)` and i should only have 8 results related to the authorId, so it should not take that long ! Here's all my code:

```
public async Task<T> GetObject<T>(string uriActionString)
        {
            T wsObject =
                default(T);
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://books.server.net");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    // connect to the server
                    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("NXXXXX:Passxxxx");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriActionString);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    wsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await((HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
                return wsObject;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw (e);
            }
        }

        public async Task<Book> viewBook(int id)
        {
            Book book = new Book();
            string urlAction = String.Format("api/book/{0}", id);
            book = await GetWSObject<Book>(urlAction);

            return book;
        }

        public string getBooksByAuthor (int authorId) {

            string result = "";

            var books = from a in db.Authors
                        where a.id == authorId
                        select new
                        {
                            id = a.id
                        };

            foreach (var book in books.ToList())
            {
                var bookdata = await ws.viewBook(book .id);
                result += this.getBookObject(book.id).name + ", ";   
            }

            return result;
        }

     /* How to return a string from a task ? */  
    foreach (var author in listOfAuthors)
      {
      booksFromAuthors.Add(new { id = author.id, book = getBooksByAuthor(author.id) // ? how convert it to a string ?  });
      }
```

Comment: How about using a debugger or a profiler?

Comment: Don't use `.Result`. Your method is async so use it properly with `await`.

Comment: @Uwe Keim, i use the chrome debugger and under the Network tab i only have "CAUTION ; request is not finished yet"...and no other informations !

Comment: Server side profiling

Comment: @Crowcoder, i have no choice to use .Result otherwise i cannot get my book object . Other suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, use `await` on the call and drop the `.Result`. What you describe happening is a deadlock. Don't ever use `.Result` in an asp.net context.

Comment: @Crowcoder, an example ? cause i cannot return a wait like an object. I need to  return a DeserializeObject. Exemple took here :  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/653eb2/consuming-web-services-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-application/

Comment: `wsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>((await(HttpResponseMessage)response).Content.ReadAsStringAsync());`

Comment: Maybe i have parentheses in the wrong places. Split the line into two lines for clarity. The point is, await the async call and then use that returned value, which is a string, to deserialize.

Comment: i already use await : HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriActionString); That mean i'm using in the wrong place ?

Comment: @Crowcoder, i updated my code, i hope you will undertand my need better now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lose the getBookObject function, you're just complicating things by starting a new Task there.

You can simply await the result from getBooksByAuthor if you make that function async.

```
public async Task<Book> getBook(int id)
{
    string urlAction = String.Format("api/book/{0}", id);
    return await GetWSObject<Book>(urlAction);
}

public async Task<string> getBooksByAuthor (int authorId) 
{
    string result = "";

    var books = from a in db.Authors
                where a.id == authorId
                select new
                {
                    id = a.id
                };

    foreach (var book in books.ToList())
    {
        var bookdata = await this.getBook(book.id);
        result += bookdata.name + ", ";   
    }

    return result; 
}
```

If you want to to make concurrent http requests, you can create a number of Tasks and use Task.WhenAll, e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30668277/1538039

Comment: Removing getBookObject will not solve the problem i have. But i will take a look at Task.WhenAll solution. Thanks

Comment: i updated my code, i hope you will undertand my need better now.

Comment: Make getBooksByAuthor async Task<string> , then await it.

Comment: I think i will have no choice finally ! Thanks. By the way i wanted to vote +1 and i voted -1 !!. I have to wait 1 hour to change it. Can you just edit your answer (by putting a space or something) so i can vote again ? cheers